# Laravel controller error: Undefined variable

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel controller, it keeps saying error like this.

> [2019-10-29 11:13:57] local.ERROR: Undefined variable: target_date
>
> {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: target_date at
>
> /home/ljw/public_html/byappscms/app/Http/Controllers/ChartController.php:78)

However, in my controller file, the variable EXIST.

**ChartController.php**

```php
public function onGetAppDailyChartData(Request $request)
{

    info("~~~~~~~~~~~" . $request->date);
    $target_date = strtotime($request->date);
    info("~~~~~~~~~~~" . $target_date);

    $appsTotal = AppsData::where('app_process', '=', '7')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('service_type', '=', 'lite')
                ->orWhere('end_time', '>', $target_date);
        })
        ->count();
}
```

And I checked the log, the values printed well.
They printed the date and the UNIX timestamp.

What possibly cause this error here?

Comment: line 78 is that the `orWhere` clause or the `info()`?

Comment: The line 78 is `orWhere` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is outside the scope of closure functions, introduce it with use

```php
$appsTotal = AppsData::where('app_process', '=', '7')
                    ->where(function($query) use ($target_date) { // <--- Here
                      $query->where('service_type', '=', 'lite')
                            ->orWhere('end_time', '>', $target_date);
                    })
                    ->count();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh wow. Fantastic! Thank you very much. I'll accept this answer 6min later.